# Mach-O Linker Error in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, xcode6.1

I get the following Linker Error in Xcode 6.1 only, Xcode 6.01 works fine:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TWvdvC7Bamberg18TourViewController2mmT_", referenced from:
      __TFC7Bamberg18TourViewControllerm2mmT_ in tours.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now I am aware about the standard suggestions. I have tried exhaustively:

- cleaning project & build folder
- deleting derived data in organizer & developer folder
- deleting previous version of the App from simulator and device
- resetting simulator
- setting "Build Active Architecture Only" to Yes/No
- playing around with compiler and architecture settings
- adding every single framework that is imaginably (including adding them all)
- make sure all implementation files are included in "Compile Sources"
- I even recreated the entire project in XCode 6.1 to make sure its not some hidden buggy derived data issue

Finally, I managed to point the source of the problem to an imported Objective C class, which is properly bridged - the error is gone when I do not make use of this class:(https://github.com/mrcrow/MRoundedButton)

If I directly open the demo project of that class in 6.1, it works fine. So I reckon it must be either a conflict of that class with my specific code while being bridged or a bridging error of that class with swift code in general.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What settings have you set for Target >> Build Settings >> Architecture?

Comment: Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)

Comment: Are you using the two classes `MRoundedButton.h` and `MRoundedButton.m` directly or Cocoa Pods?

Comment: I'm using them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have problem in your Swift code or triggered a bug in the Swift compiler. The symbols your linker complains about are Swift symbols (as identified by the `__T` prefix). When passed to the `swift-demangle` tool, the symbols translate to:

```
_TFC7Bamberg18TourViewControllerm2mmT_ ---> Bamberg.TourViewController.mm.materializeForSet : ()
_TWvdvC7Bamberg18TourViewController2mmT_ ---> direct field offset for Bamberg.TourViewController.mm : ()
```

So in your `TourViewController` you seem to reference a field `mm`, but the linker can't find it. Maybe you can rewrite/reorganize your code to avoid/fix this problem.

Comment: Odd, because if I do not use the above mentioned ObjC class, the Swift TourViewController works fine as it is. But I'll try to play around with changing things anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Never mind, you were dead right. I had to declare mm (which is a dictionary) inside a method and not globally. No clue why, but it works now. Thanks a lot for putting me on track.